# Getting the tuple with max second component value

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples, max

I have a list:

```
l = [("abc",0.9), ("abc1",0.95), ("abc2",0.8), ("abc3",0.9)]
```

I want to get the tuple with the highest second tuple value,
i.e.

```
("abc1", 0.95)
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You'd use the `key` argument to the [`max()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max):

```
max(l, key=lambda i: i[1])
```

You can also use [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to produce a callable here:

```
from operator import itemgetter
max(l, key=itemgetter(1))
```

Demo:

```
>>> l=[("abc",0.9),("abc1",0.95),("abc2",0.8),("abc3",0.9)]
>>> max(l, key=lambda i: i[1])
('abc1', 0.95)
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> max(l, key=itemgetter(1))
('abc1', 0.95)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `max` function, with the `key` parameter as a function which can give the second element of each tuple to compare, like this

```
print max(l, key=lambda x: x[1])
# ('abc1', 0.95)
```

Otherwise you can use the builtin `itemgetter` operator, like this

```
from operator import itemgetter
print max(l, key=itemgetter(1))
# ('abc1', 0.95)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `key` keyword argument in the built-in `max` function: you can pass it a function which looks at the element at index 1 (i.e. the second element) of the tuple:

```
>>> max(l, key=lambda x: x[1])
("abc1", 0.95)
```